# Error building Flutter iOS app - Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

My app is not building for the iOS simulator.

I've tried a clean, looks like it's a Firebase issue.

I'm using these versions:

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
firebase_core: ^0.5.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1

```
In file included from /Users/ramshaw/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.5.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.m:5:
In file included from /Users/ramshaw/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.5.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h:6:
/Users/ramshaw/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.5.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:123:4: error: expected a type
+ (FlutterError *_Nonnull)createFlutterErrorFromCode:(NSString *_Nonnull)code
   ^
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

1. Created a new Flutter project
2. Copied over the pub spec.yaml file, checked the app was building.
3. Repeated step 2 for the rest of my lib files, one file at a time.

Why one file at a time?

'cause if I replaced the folder, it did not build.

I'm happy my app is building again but not sure why and that doesn't make me happy.